# How to Display IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Model>> with an editor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates, igrouping

I have a bunch of items that I have grouped up by Header.

I would like to display them on the page with the header text followed by the editor template for each individual item.

I tried using nested templates as follows:

Main Page:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.GroupedItems, "ListofGrouping");
```

ListofGrouping Editor Template:

```
@model IList<IGrouping<string, Model>>
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i],"IGrouping")
}
```

IGrouping Editor Template:

```
@model IGrouping<string, Model>

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Key)
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

This works up till the last line. I get all the header values but the individual items are not displayed.

If I can't get it to work this way I will just use a data grid and do the grouping there, but I figured this should be possible in MVC3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
You must write your own EditorTemplate for IGrouping.

Sample of EditorTemplate for IGrouping:
**Model:**

```
public class Row
{
    public Row()
    {
    }

    public Row(string key, int value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        IEnumerable<Row> dict = new[] { new Row("1", 1), new Row("1", 2), new Row("1", 3), new Row("2", 2), new Row("2", 3), new Row("2", 4) };
        var grouped = dict.GroupBy(c => c.Key).First();
        //var grouplist = grouped.Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<int>> (c.Key, c.Select(b=>b.Value)));
        return View(grouped);
    }

    public ActionResult Post(IEnumerable<Row> Model)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**View Index:**

```
@model IGrouping<string, MvcApplication1.Models.Row>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("Post", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel("IGrouping")
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

**EditorTemplate IGrouping.cshtml:**

```
@model IGrouping<string, MvcApplication1.Models.Row>
@{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Key)
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var pair in Model.Select(c => c))
    {
        @Html.Hidden(string.Format("Model[{0}].Key", i), pair.Key)
        @Html.TextBox(string.Format("Model[{0}].Value", i), pair.Value)
        i++;
    }
}
```

More about binding Collections you can read there:[Hancelman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Comment: That's actually a built in template, it should work with or without the "Collection" parameter.

Comment: "Collection" parameter means that you use EditorTemplate Collection.cshtml for your model, where your model is IGrouping<string, Model>.

Comment: I update my post with working sample. I hope it will help you.

Comment: To your first comment, yes understand that. Using the Collection template for IGrouping<string,Model> should work just fine because IGrouping<string,Model> implements IEnumerable<Model> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx). I will reply to your updated answer in another comment.

Comment: Your updated answer will work, however it does not allow me to use the Editor template that I created for my Model. I will mark this as correct if no one can figure out a way to make this work with an Editor template (for the individual Model objects).

Comment: I can help you with your editor template if you show it. I assume that you can use it through extension method to html helper.

Comment: The editor template is fine (I'm using it on another screen already). The problem is using it in this scenario. I tried @dbaseman method but the framework seems to ignore that. I never get any errors, the items just don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the **IGrouping** is also an **IEnumerable**.  So instead of using `@Html.EditorForModel()`, enumerate over the items.

```
@model IGrouping<string, Model>

@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Key)
foreach (var grp in Model)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => grp)
}
```